# How to effectively work on combinations along one dimension in np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, numba

Given `S` being an `n x m` matrix, as a numpy array, I want to call function `f` on pairs of `(S[i], S[j])` to calculate a particular value of interest, stored in a matrix with dimensions `n x n`. In my particular case the function `f` is commutative so `f(x,y) = f(y,x)`.

With all this in mind I am wondering if I can do any tricks to speed this up as much as I can, `n` can be fairly large.

When I time the function f, it's around a couple of microseconds, which is as expected. It's a pretty straightforward calculation. Below I show you the timings I got, compared with `max()` and `sum()` for reference.

```
In [19]: %timeit sum(s[11])
4.68 µs ± 56.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit max(s[11])
3.61 µs ± 64.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit f(s[11], s[21], 50, 10, 1e-5)
1.23 µs ± 7.25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit f(s[121], s[321], 50, 10, 1e-5)
1.26 µs ± 31.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

However when I time the overall processing time for a 500x50 sample data (resulting in 500 x 500 /2 = 125K comparisons), the overall time blows up significantly (into minutes). I would have expected something like 0.2-0.3 seconds (1.25E5 * 2E-6 sec/calc).

```
In [12]: @jit
    ...: def testf(s, n, m, p):
    ...:     tol = 1e-5
    ...:     sim = np.zeros((n,n))
    ...:     for i in range(n):
    ...:         for j in range(n):
    ...:             if i > j:
    ...:                 delta = p[i] - p[j]
    ...:                 if delta < 0:
    ...:                     res = f(s[i], s[j], m, abs(delta), tol) # <-- max(s[i])
    ...:                 else:
    ...:                     res = f(s[j], s[i], m, delta, tol) # <-- sum(s[j])
    ...:                 sim[i][j] = res
    ...:                 sim[j][i] = res
    ...:     return sim
```

In code above I have changed the lines where `res` is assigned to `max()` and `sum()` (commented out parts) for testing and the code executes approx 100 times faster, even though the functions themselves are slower compared to my function `f()`

Which brings me to my questions:

1. Can I avoid the double loop to speed this up? Ideally I want to be able to run this for matrices where n = 1E5 size. (Comment: since the max and sum, functions work considerably faster, my guess is that the for loops isn't the bottleneck here, but still good to know if there is a better way)
2. What may cause the severe slowdown with my function, if it's not the double for loop?

**EDIT**

The specifics of the function f was asked, by some comments. It's iterating over two arrays and checks the number of values in the two arrays that are "close enough". I removed the comments and changes some variable names but the logic is as shown below. It was interesting to note that `math.isclose(x,y,rel_tol)` which is equivalent to the if-statements i have below, makes the code significantly slower, probably due to library call?

```
from numba import jit
@jit 
def f(arr1, arr2, n, d, rel_tol):

    counter = 0
    i,j,k = 0,0,0   
    while (i < n and j < n and k < n):
        val = arr1[j] + d
        if abs(arr1[i] - arr2[k]) < rel_tol * max(arr1[i], arr2[k]):
            counter += 1
            i += 1
            k += 1
        elif abs(val - arr2[k]) < rel_tol * max(val, arr2[k]):
            counter += 1
            j += 1
            k += 1
        else: 
            # incremenet the index corresponding to the lightest
            if arr1[i] <= arr2[k] and arr1[i] <= val:
                if i < n: 
                    i += 1
            elif val <= arr1[i] and val <= arr2[k]:
                if j < n:
                    j += 1
            else: 
                k += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: If your f() function is simple, can you vectorize it?  That's the usual way to get rid of the looping around calls to f() -- write it as a function that takes your vector S[] and returns the matrix you're looking for (or just a lower/upper diagonal).  Can you share f(), or its general form?

Comment: What is your function f? Can you give an example and what dependencies f has (eg. only numpy or more). Calling a non compiled function is deadly slow in Python....

Comment: @payne code for f is added.

Comment: @max9111 if I remove the `jit` it goes much slower

Comment: Can you add some testdata, Numba and Python version? I tried it with n=500
m=50
s=np.random.rand(n*m).reshape(n,m)
p=np.random.rand(n*2) and got 110ms

Comment: @max9111 the array I had for `p` was wrongly sized apparently, it was a 2D array where I thought it was a 1D array.. I get about 300ms for the entire calculation now that I fixed that miss. Did you get that timing with or without jit?

Comment: Thanks for posting f().  Given that, my guess is that your performance variations are due to cache interplay.  Since your calculations involve accessing the arrays in various patterns, you can end up with all sorts of weird interactions between interations.  I will look more later to see if there's a way to vectorize some/all of f().